# Sending email stopped working using anything@testapp.appspotmail.com?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to send an email using the java api. I've got my app running live, no custom domain, in fact it's just a default project. Billing is not enabled. My app name is 'testapp'.

I'm using this email address for the sender:

```
admin@testapp.appspotmail.com
```

That seems to be ok if I'm reading the docs correctly (criteria #2):

> For security purposes, the sender address of a message must be one of the following:
>
> 1. The Gmail or Google Apps Account of the user who is currently signed in
> 2. Any email address of the form anything@appname.appspotmail.com or anything@appalias.appspotmail.com
> 3. Any email address listed in the Cloud Platform Console under Email API Authorized Senders

The email was sent successfully twice, but now it has stopped working (same sender address, same recipient address). Nothing appears in the recipient's spam.

I can see in the quota page that the # of emails-sent keeps incrementing. But nothing is actually going through.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Do you see anything within the application logs? You should be able to send up to 100 emails a day. You also may want to enable bounces to see if this is whats happening. (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/bounce)

Comment: Hi yeah no exception in the final message send call (Transport.send(msg);). Nothing else in the logs. I didn't know about the bounce feedback, I'll try setting that up, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue that is currently being tracked on the App Engine [public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12786). Please feel free to star this issue for updates.